# django radio button ModelForm across multiple fields as values

Tags: django, django-models, modelform

I am using django to make a multiple choice Question Answer web app.
What I have:

a Model for a section:

```
class Section(models.Model):
  section_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=section_choices)
  text = models.TextField()
  equestions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

  class Meta:
    app_label = "myapp"
    db_table = "section"
    managed = True
```

A Model for Question (where i store all the questions i have made):

```
class Question(models.Model):
  question_text = models.TextField()
  question_type = models.CharField(choices=question_type_choices,
                                 max_length=30)
  # MCQ Fields
  choice_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  choice_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  choice_3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  choice_4 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  correct_answer = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  users_answer = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  marks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=2)

  class Meta:
    app_label = "myapp"
    db_table = "question"
    managed = True
```

As you can see a question has 4 choices and they are present in choice_1, choice_2, choice_3 choice_4 
What i need is a modelForm where i can display one whole section in a page with Radio button and note the responses of all the questions with a single submit button. Is this possible using forms and without using too much javascript with these models?

Comment: I am also looking for that answer, were you able to figure out? ;)